# Mailchimp API - Subscribe to list

Tags: php, json, mailchimp

I'm working on adding a script to my site for a MailChimp subscribe form. I think I have everything setup right but when I hit the subscribe button I'm getting a blank page.

Here is the script I have currently

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'Mailchimp.php';

$apikey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($apikey);

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $id = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    $email = array(
        'email' => trim($_POST['email'])
    );

    $result = $Mailchimp->$lists->subscribe($id, $email, $double_optin=false, $replace_interests=false);

    var_dump($result);

}

echo "TESTING";
```

So I'm not getting the $result variable or "TESTING echo'd right now, so I assume I must be doing something simple wrong. Anyone see anything obvious? I believe I'm using the correct default JSON format. (keys have been X'd out, but the one's I'm using are correct)

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!!

EDIT: I have updated the code to something I believe to be more correct, but it still isn't working. I could really use some help on this.

Comment: Turn error_reporting on.

Comment: Here's the error I'm seeing now "[18-Mar-2014 11:55:21] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mailchimp_Templates' not found in /home7/brandog1/public_html/sticknfind/Mailchimp.php on line 264"

Comment: Looks like one of the MailChimp php files was corruput? I'm downloading the api again and we'll see where that takes me.

Comment: Corrected this error, but I'm still getting directed to a blank page with no results. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you still have error_reporting turned on?

Comment: Yes, not getting any more errors logged.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've handled AJAX email submissions in the past for MailChimp's API (MCAPI):

```
define("MC_API_KEY", "Your mailchimp API key");
define("MC_API_LIST", "The list ID to subscribe user to");
define("EMAIL_TO", "email address in case subscription fails");

require "MailChimp.API.class.php";

function json($error = true, $message = "Unknown error") { 
  die(json_encode(array("error" => $error, "message" => $message)));
}

if(!empty($_POST)) {
  $email = !empty($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? $_POST['email'] : false;

  if($email !== false) {    
    $api = new MCAPI(MC_API_KEY);
    $result = $api->listSubscribe(MC_API_LIST, $email);

    if($api->errorCode || !$result) {
      if(isset($api->errorCode) && $api->errorCode == 214) { // already subscribed
        json(true, "You are already subscribed!");
      } else {
        $error = "Unable to save user email via MailChimp API!\n\tCode=".$api->errorCode."\n\tMsg=".$api->errorMessage."\n\n";
        $headers = "From: your@email.com\r\nReply-to: <{$email}>\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

        mail(EMAIL_TO, "Newsletter Submission FAIL [MC API ERROR]", "{$error}Saved info:\nFrom: {$email}\n\nSent from {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']} on ".date("F jS, Y \@ g:iA e"), $headers);

        json(false, "Thank you - your email will be subscribed shortly!");
      }
    } else {
      json(false, "Thanks - A confirmation link has been sent to your email!");
    }
  } else {
    json(true, "Please enter your valid email address");
  }
} else json();
```

Comment: Yeah. Seems to be a lot more resources / tutorials out there for the old API. A lot of mailchimp's own documentation references the old api which is pretty disappointing.

Comment: We'll still continue to use v1.3 as there are other versions still marked as deprecated but not removed.. so it'll probably be around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

Here is the correct code - hopefully this will help others looking to use the new api -

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'Mailchimp.php';

$apikey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$Mailchimp = new Mailchimp($apikey);

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $id = "XXXXXXXXXX";
    $email = array(
        'email' => trim($_POST['email'])
    );

    $result = $Mailchimp->lists->subscribe($id, $email, $merge_vars=null, $double_optin=false, $replace_interests=false);

}
```